# How to make a copy of a string and return its address, assign that to a pointer and print the new string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I'm writing a function that gets a string, allocates memory on the heap that's enough to create a copy, creates a copy and returns the address of the beginning of the new copy.
In main I would like to be able to print the new copy and afterwards use free() to free the memory. I think the actual function works although I am not the char pointer has to be static, or does it?

The code in main does not work fine...

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int make_copy(char arr[]);

int main()
{
    char arrr[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','\0'};

    char *ptr;
    ptr=make_copy(arrr);

    printf("%s",ptr);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}


int make_copy(char arr[])
{
    static char *str_ptr;
    str_ptr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(arr));

    int i=0;
    for(;i<sizeof str_ptr/sizeof(char);i++)
        str_ptr[i]=arr[i];

    return (int)str_ptr;
}
```

OK, so based on the comments. A revised version:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* make_copy(char arr[]);

int main()
{
    char arrr[]={"abcdef\0"};

    char *ptr=make_copy(arrr);

    printf("%s",ptr);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}


char* make_copy(char arr[])
{
    static char *str_ptr;
    str_ptr=(char*)malloc(strlen(arr)+1);

    int i=0;
    for(;i<strlen(arr)+1;i++)
        str_ptr[i]=arr[i];

    return str_ptr;
}
```

Or even better:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* make_copy(char arr[]);

int main()
{
    char arrr[]={"abcdef\0"};

    printf("%s",make_copy(arrr));
    getchar();

    return 0;
}


char* make_copy(char arr[])
{
    char *str_ptr;
    str_ptr=(char*)malloc(strlen(arr)+1);
    return strcpy(str_ptr,arr);
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning `int`?

Comment: Why would you **ever** declare your function to return `int` when it needs to return a `char *`? Also, `sizeof(arr)` doesn't do what you think it does, `sizeof(char)` is always one, `sizeof(str_ptr)` doesn't do what you think it does either, you are missing a NUL terminator, and the `make_copy()` function leaks memory. That's all. You need to **learn C** before trying to write programs in it.

Comment: I was asked to return the address of the allocated space... I could have returned a char pointer which would made things easier, but that's not what I was requested.

Comment: @user34920 The address of the allocated pointer is `&str_pointer`, but it's **still** not an `int`. It's a `char **`. What are you even trying to do with that poor `int`? I mean, how come? Just **use your common sense, man.**

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. This function exists in the standard library under the name `strdup`. Returning `char *` is exactly what you are asked to do. It is an address.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks fundamental knowledge of the language being used.

Comment: @H2CO3 - saw my latest edit?

Comment: @user34920 I did. For some reason, you didn't respect our advice and you are still casting the return value of malloc, which is bad. Also, `char arr[] = { "abcdef\0" }` should be `char arr[] = "abcdef";` -- tue trailing extra 0 is superfluous, so are the extraneous curly braces (a string literal is itself an array and can act as an initialzer list without braces).

Comment: @H2CO3 You are against casting the return value of malloc because it's a non prototyped function? Perhaps a very old compiler would assume the return type is int and that would result in casting an int to a pointer and if the pointer type is larger (wider?) than an int something bad might happen. However seems like GCC (which I am using) knows malloc, even without stdin. To be fair it does give a warning but works fine.

Comment: @user34920 no, that's not the reason. the cast is harmful. warnings should always be fixed. Read the answer Unwind linked to in is answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 Just to be clear, a warning pops up when stdio.h is not included, that should not be left that way. agreed. Otherwise no warning. I didn't understand where you suggest the answer is.

Comment: @user34920 [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169)

Comment: @H2CO3 - I think the reason I gave might actually be a better argument. Not including stdio.h and casting the return value of malloc would probably won't cause any issues. Size mismatch might actually cause a run-time crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there are some issues with your code:

1. Don't use `int` when you mean `char *`. That's just wrong.
2. Don't list characters when defining a string, write `char arrr[] = "abcdef";`
3. Don't scale string alloations by `sizeof (char)`; that's always 1 so it's pointless.
4. Don't re-implement `strcpy()` to copy a string.
5. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169)
6. Don't make local variables `static` for no reason.
7. Don't use `sizeof` on an array passed to a function; it doesn't work. You must use `strlen()`.
8. Don't omit including space for the string terminator, you must add 1 to the length of the string.

**UPDATE** Your third attempt is getting closer. :) Here's how I would write it:

```
char * make_copy(const char *s)
{
  if(s != NULL)
  {
    const size_t size = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *d = malloc(size);
    if(d != NULL)
      strcpy(d, s);
    return d;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

This gracefully handles a `NULL` argument, and checks that the memory allocation succeeded before using the memory.

Comment: This is shameless self-advertisement! Linking to your own answer! :P

Comment: @H2CO3 I prefer to think of it as supporting arguments. :) Many people seem hardwired to do that cast, I find it helpful to actually provide arguments but don't want to repeat myself all over the place.

Comment: I wasn't being serious :P perhaps that answer of yours is my single favorite post on Stack Overflow (apart from Jon Skeet facts, of course).

Comment: Gee, thanks! :) It was just downvoted, I guess that wasn't you then. :) I'll take a positive comparison to The Skeet any day, thankyouverymuch.

Comment: Oh gosh. I see, it was downvoted... some people just **really** don't know what they are doing (and, first and foremost, what they *should* be doing... too much "C/C++" "programmers" out there...)

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(arr)` will not give the exact size. pass the length of array to the function if you want to compute array size.

When pass the array to function it will decay to pointer, we cannot find the array size using pointer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i mean array size using pointer. i will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `sizeof` to determine the size of your string in `make_copy`, use `strlen`.

Second, why are you converting a pointer (`char*`) to an integer? A `char*` is already a pointer (a memory address), as you can see if you do `printf("address: %x\n", ptr);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strdup(const char *str)
{
    char *s = (char*)malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;
    return strcpy(s, str);
}

int main()
{
    char *s = strdup("hello world");
    puts(s);
    free(s);
}
```

Comment: that's pretty similar to the edited version I added, however you also covered a NULL case. BTW - writing char *strdup(const char *str) or just char *strdup(char str[]) is the same right? I understand that the pointer to an array is a const and perhaps the compiler will note something about it, however it does not matter here and *str is the same is str[] since C knows both are pointers right?

Comment: the string "hello world" is a pointer to a character array literal, therefore it's type is const char *. Non-constant character arrays will also work with this function definition. Your compiler might throw a warning if you use char str[] and you pass in a literal string.

Answer (score -1):

Points
~ return char* inside of int.
~ you can free the memory using  below line

```
 if(make_copy!=NULL)
  free(make_copy)
```

Below is the modified code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
char* make_copy(char arr[]);

int main()
{
    char arrr[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','\0'};

    char *ptr;
    ptr=make_copy(arrr,sizeof(arrr)/sizeof(char));

    printf("%s",ptr);
    printf("%p\n %p",ptr,arrr);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}


char* make_copy(char arr[],int size)
{
     char *str_ptr=NULL;
    str_ptr=(char*)malloc(size+1);

    int i=0;
    for(;i<size;i++)
        str_ptr[i]=arr[i];
       str_ptr[i]=0;

    return str_ptr;
}
```